# Expect function argument by shell function: calling in shell script

Tags: shell, sh, expect

I Have one script named `test.sh`.

which contains function as,

```
APPFE_Routes()
{


set filename [lindex $argv 0]

expect -c '

spawn ssh admin@10.43.67.18

expect "Password: "

send "Admin@1234\r"

expect "~]$"

send "su\r"

expect "Password: "

send "500tps\r"

expect "]#"

send "put ifconfig grep -i $filename\r"

expect -re "]#"

send "exit\r"

'

}
```

I am calling it down in the `test.sh` script.

```
APPFE_Routes mkt mkt1
```

I want these `mkt` and `mkt1` variables to pass through expect script function
By the above code.

I am not able to get the same result.
Actually i am getting these variables from one file into shell, then need to pass to expect function inside shell.
Separate expect script is not required.
Solution is highly appreciated.

Comment: `set filename [lindex $argv 0]` is a `Tcl` command and it will not work on the shell script.

Comment: Thanks Dinesh..Could you please suggest me another way

Comment: The shell equivalent is `filename=$1`.

Comment: Like most questions involving `expect` on Stack Overflow, it would be better to use public key encryption for `ssh` and configure `sudo` on the remote end to allow the command to be executed without a password; then the entire function reduces to `APPFE_Routes() { ssh admin@10.43.67.18 "put ifconfig grep -i $filename\r"; }`. (The `put` doesn't look like a shell command, but that's a different question.)

Answer (score 1):

I was going to suggest you do

```
shell_func() {
    expect -c '
        your expect code
    ' "$@"
}
```

but expect can't handle reading arguments after `-c`

```
$ expect -c 'puts [join $argv \n]' foo bar baz
can't read "argv": no such variable
    while executing
"join $argv \n"
    invoked from within
"puts [join $argv \n]"
couldn't read file "foo": no such file or directory
```

So I suggest you put the arguments to your shell function in the environment for expect:

```
APPFE_Routes()
{
    FILENAME="$1" expect -c '
        puts "hello $env(FILENAME)"
    '
}
APPFE_Routes world
```

```
hello world
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you're writing TCL code.  if you have `tclsh` installed, then you can set the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to #!/usr/bin/tclsh and then write TCL all you want.

if you want to stick to POSIX shell code, then that `set` statement probably should read:

```
filename="$1"
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi glenn jackman and ALL,

Thanks for all your responses. I got my work done with the help of you all.
But i did something else to avoid this problem.
`code`
APPFE_IP=${lines_ary[i]};

SIG_IP=${lines_ary[i+1]};

SIG_Gateway=${lines_ary[i+2]};

APP_IP=${lines_ary[i+3]};

APP_GATEWAY=${lines_ary[i+4]};

RDS1_IP=${lines_ary[i+5]};

RDS1_APP=${lines_ary[i+6]};

RDS1_GATEWAY=${lines_ary[i+7]};

fi

######APPFE ROUTES to RDS1

{

/usr/bin/expect << EOF

spawn ssh admin@$APPFE_IP

expect "Password: "

send "Admin@1234\r"

expect -re "~]$"

send "su -\r"

expect "Password: "

send "500tps\r"

expect -re "~]# "

send "route add -host $RDS1_APP gw $APP_GATEWAY\r"

expect -re "~]# "

send "exit\r"

EOF

}

`code`